# HTC One [M7] Lollipop update fails

Tags: updates, 5.0-lollipop, ota-update, htc-one

I tried to update my HTC One [m7] unlocked/international to the new Android Lollipop with the OTA update that got pushed yesterday. However, it keeps failing.
My HTC is rooted, and is currently running 6.12.161.9 (trying to update to 7.18.616.2). It is S-ON and has an hboot 1.57. 
Now, the problem keeps appearing in the following way: (I have the correct stock recovery on the phone)
The phone starts the update process normaly. It goes to the recovery and the progress bar starts to move. However as soon as it reaches about 1/4 of its way (always the same), it stops the installation and returns to the recovery title screen (the red triangle and exclamation mark). When I then press volume up and power button to see the recovery menu, it gives me the following readout at the bottom on the console:
Code:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
L50QCT.01.102.008
Package expects build fingerprint of htc/vodafone_uk/m7:4.4.3/KTU84L/366813.9:user/release-keys 
or htc/vodafone_uk/m7:5.0.2/LRX22G/476210.2:user/release-keys; 
this device has htc/vodafone_uk/m7:4.4.3/KTU84L/366813.5:user/release-keys.
Installation aborted.
Write host_mode:0 done
```

It gives me this readout every time, and the only difference in expectation and device, is this:
The update expects 366813.**9**, the device has 366813.**5**. What does this difference mean? What is .9 and what is .5, and how can I fix this?

I would be very happy for any help possible. Thanks in advance!

- Cheers

EDIT: Fixed, turns out I had the wrong recovery installed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the following and it will solve your issue (install correctly): Copy the zip file to pc form "Phone\Download\OTA_M7_UL_L50_SENSE60_MR_HTC_Europe_7.19.401.2-6.09.401.11_release_XXXX.zip"

1. Extract "firmware.zip" from OTA_M7_UL_L50_SENSE60_MR_HTC_Europe_7.19.401.2-6.09.401.11_XXXX.zip
2. Extract "recovery.img" from "firmware.zip"
3. Activate USB debugging on your device (if not already)
4. Reboot your device on bootloader. I believe holding down "Power" + "VOL+" will do it (if not google it). You can use ADB command as well. "adb reboot-bootloader"
5. install the recovery using ADB command "fastboot flash recovery recovery.img"
6. Now try to update once again form OTA and it will work.

To avoid redownload this large file:

1. Copy the zip file which you copied from Phone to phone\update.zip
2. Reboot phone to recovery
3. Apply Update from Phone Memory (As HTC one to not have external memory)
4. Choose the Update.zip file

I hope you get the idea even if few steps might be slightly off.

Thanks
Shurid

Answer (score 0):

A change to the way the update process for lolli works means that for phones and tablets that have been modified, the OTA update will not work.

However, this does not mean that all is lost. While slightly annoying, if you have modified your system partition all you need to do is reflash your device with a stock Android image. With this done you can then reattempt the OTA update and it should be successful.

Another option is to manually upgrade to Lollipop. Factory images for Android 5.0 Lollipop are available for some Nexus devices – we've looked at how you can install the update on a Nexus 5 and how to upgrade a Nexus 7 – and images will be made available for other handsets in the coming weeks and months.

-Source: android pit (http://www.androidpit.com/android-5-0-lollipop-ota-update-fail)

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I apparently just had the wrong recovery installed!

Comment: @Phil - love it when it's that easy!